# How is Anderson Localization a quantum-mechanical phenomenon? How to compare it with classical case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, anderson-localization

I was reading book of *50 Years of Anderson localization*, which mentions that it highlights wave particle duality. What does it mean? About this localization I have also read that we can understand it in terms of impurity in semiconductors. Can some one please give the main theme behind Anderson localization including its comparison with classical case?

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434666/what-is-main-theme-behind-anderson-localization-and-how-it-is-one-particle-loca ?